# Datagridview atualizando pelo form filho

Tags: c#

Tenho um form principal (`form1`) onde carrego um `datagridviwer` e preciso fazer o seguinte: tenho um segundo form (`form2`) que faz exclusão da linha selecionada no `datagridviwer` (`form1`), só que preciso fazer que quando eu excluir a linha do `datagridviwer` com o botão no `form2`, ele fecha a tela do `form2` e volta pra tela do `form1` já atualizado, ou seja, com a linha deletada, como posso fazer isso?

Segue meu código que atualiza o `datagridviwer`;

```
{
    conm.Open();
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select 
                                        sa.Cod_Solicitacao,
                                        cli.Cliente,
                                        cli.Contato,
                                        sa.Solicitante,
                                        sa.Representante,
                                        sa.Area_Atuacao,
                                        sa.Tipo_Envio,
                                        sa.Separador,
                                        convert(varchar(10), cast(Data_Entrega as date), 103) as Finalizado,
                                        cli.Id_Cliente,
                                        sa.Id_Solicitacao
                                from tbl_SolicitacaoAmostra as sa
                                inner join tbl_Cliente as cli with(nolock) on cli.Id_Cliente = sa.Id_Cliente
                                inner join tbl_Produto as pro with(nolock) on pro.Id_Solicitacao = sa.Id_Solicitacao
                                where sa.Deletado is null and cli.Deletado is null and pro.Deletado is null
                                group by sa.Cod_Solicitacao, cli.Cliente, cli.Contato, sa.Solicitante, sa.Representante, sa.Separador, sa.Area_Atuacao, sa.Tipo_Envio, sa.Separador, sa.Data_Entrega, cli.Id_Cliente, sa.Id_Solicitacao", conm);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds, "Solicitacao");
    DGW_solictacao.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    conm.Close();
}
MessageBox.Show("Solicitação excluida com sucesso!!!");
this.Dispose();
```

Comment: Mas vc efetua a exclusão efetivamente na tabela, porque se sim, é só vc sar um this.clouse(); e chamar o método que carrega o data grid novamente que eu vai fazer uma nova pesquisa com as linhas excluídas.
Se não for isso não ficou claro a pergunta

Comment: Renan muito obrigado. deu certinho aqui era isso mesmo que eu precisava. vlw.

Comment: Que Legal, Então vou colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mas você efetua a exclusão efetivamente na tabela, porque se sim, é só você usar um `this.clouse();` e chamar o método que carrega o data `Grid` novamente que eu vai fazer uma nova pesquisa com as linhas excluídas.